# sum specific values in table postgres

Tags: postgresql

So I am new to postgres and having some issues, this is my table:
[image]

I would like a query to return the table in this format:

[image]

I would like the area to be distinct with the sum of all sales in area1 and for area2, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need GROUP BY

```
SELECT
  Area,
  SUM(sales) AS "sales"
FROM myTable
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY area;
```